# Laravel returning root view instead of static content

Tags: file, static, laravel-4, public

I have one route:

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

And `HomeController` has one action `getIndex` which works correctly.  However, when browsing to `http://localhost:4040/public/style.css`, the application returns the view from `HomeController::getIndex`.  What gives??  Shouldn't it return the static file `style.css`??  I have confirmed that the CSS file does in-fact exist in the public folder.

To be clear, I'm running the app like this:

```
php -S localhost:4040 server.php
```

**EDIT**:

Hmmm, so the following seems to work:

1) Serve the project with:

```
php artisan serve
```

2) Reference files without the `public/` prefix.

What does the `php artisan serve` command do so differently??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using `Route::controller()`, if you look at the `php artisan routes`, the `getIndex` route has a optional parameters `{one?}/{two?}/...` and since that parameters have no matching pattern `style.css` get caught by the `{one?}`. This is the completely expected behavior, with `index.php`.

However, using `php artisan serve`, the `server.php` file gets called first.

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$uri = urldecode($uri);

$paths = require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/paths.php';

$requested = $paths['public'].$uri;

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists($requested))
{
    return false;
}

require_once $paths['public'].'/index.php';
```

You can clearly see that it checks if the file is real in `if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists($requested))`, and if it is, it stops calling the `index.php` that may process it as a route parameter, and instead returns a real file.